Trying to have logging in nestjs and grapql but couldn't able to get response status as per the altair is giving
When working with GraphQL and NestJS, you may encounter an issue where all responses from your GraphQL API have an HTTP status code of 200 OK, even when there are GraphQL-level errors. This behavior is typical because GraphQL, as a specification, doesn't rely on HTTP status codes to indicate errors; instead, errors are included in the response body under the errors key.
Before you post your question on Stack Overflow, here's a more detailed explanation and a draft for your Stack Overflow question that includes all relevant details to maximize the chance of receiving a helpful answer.
Explanation of the Issue
In a standard REST API, different HTTP status codes are used to indicate the nature of the response, with codes like 400 Bad Request, 404 Not Found, or 500 Internal Server Error indicating various types of errors. However, GraphQL typically returns 200 OK for all responses, including those that contain errors, unless there's a server-level issue that prevents the server from returning a response at all. Instead, GraphQL includes any errors in the response body in an errors field, which details what went wrong while processing the query.
This can be confusing when implementing logging or error handling middleware because these typically rely on HTTP status codes to determine the outcome of a request.
Draft for Stack Overflow Question
Title:
Handling GraphQL Errors in NestJS: Interceptor Always Returns HTTP 200 Status Even on Errors
Body:
I'm implementing a logging interceptor in a NestJS application that uses GraphQL. I've noticed that even when GraphQL queries result in errors, the HTTP status code of the responses is always 200 OK. I understand that GraphQL handles errors internally and includes them in the response body under an errors key, but for logging purposes, I'd like to capture more accurate HTTP status codes based on the presence of these errors.
Here's the relevant part of my interceptor:
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LogsService } from '../logs/logs.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private readonly logsService: LogsService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req, res } = ctx.getContext();
    const info = ctx.getInfo();

    const now = Date.now();
    const requestLog = {
      // log details...
    };

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async (data) => {
        // Handling response
        const isError = data.errors && data.errors.length > 0;
        const status = isError ? 500 : res.statusCode;

        // Log the response here
      }),
      catchError(async (error) => {
        // Error handling
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    );
  }
}


